# Both if and else part are executing

Tags: c++

```
  /*Q_INVOKABLE*/ void LinkDestUI::selectDeselectSingleDestination(int iXmlId)
{
   for(const auto &subNode : m_nodeColl)
   {
      if(bMultipleSelect())
      {
         if(subNode->getXmlId() == iXmlId)
         {
             LOG(Severity_Error)<<"1 ";
            subNode->setbSelected(!subNode->bSelected());
         }
      }
      else
      {
         if(subNode->getXmlId() == iXmlId)
         {
             LOG(Severity_Error)<<"2 ";
            subNode->setbSelected(!subNode->bSelected());
         }
         else
         {
             LOG(Severity_Error)<<"3 ";
            subNode->setbSelected(false);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When i execute my code then compiler goes to else part and exceute both if and else statement inside the else part. why?

Comment: Debug it, learn to use breakpoints. We will never know what bMultipleSelect() and subNode->getXmlId() return

Comment: its just only a variable

Comment: Show us a complete example with the data where this is happening.

Comment: how is it possible, both if and else part are executing inside else part

Comment: *Both if and else part are executing* -- No they're not.  You think they're both executed by not analyzing your program more carefully.

Comment: Can you verify whether, if and else blocks are both executing in the same iteration?

Comment: It's very unlikely that a compile would generate code to run the if block as well as the else block.

Comment: Its is possible it is executing the if part in an iteration of the for loop, then the else part in a different iteration.

Comment: It shows the input you use, and the output you get. Also you should not use tags unnecessarily, for example Qt is a tag that is not suitable for this question since it has nothing to do with any kind of Qt, understand that the tags are used to filter questions.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta -- This seems to be the case of you being convinced your code has no bugs, and shocked that the program works in a different way than what you thought you coded.  No, there is no magic -- your program is working as you wrote it -- if it doesn't execute a certain set of code, it is a bug that you need to fix.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta - You should start with question instead of the code right away. Also did you go through it debugging step by step OR you are saying it based on just seeing the output. Go through each step in debugger.

Comment: I suspect that `m_nodeColl` has more elements than you think.

Answer (score 1):

That seems ... (temporarily increasing my tactfulness attribute so as to avoid offending) ... rather unlikely :-)

It's probably because the code is being entered more than once and you're just assuming it's executing both parts because of the output.

My advice would be to change the code in the outer `else` to be:

```
LOG(Severity_Error)<<"Starting inner if ";
if(subNode->getXmlId() == iXmlId)
{
    LOG(Severity_Error)<<"2 ";
    subNode->setbSelected(!subNode->bSelected());
}
else
{
    LOG(Severity_Error)<<"3 ";
    subNode->setbSelected(false);
}
LOG(Severity_Error)<<"Ending inner if ";
```

You should *not* see both blocks executing without an intervening end/start message set.

Comment: see my above full code

Comment: @ShubhamGupta, your full code has the same problem as your original code. There is nothing in it to *prove* both the `if` and `else` blocks are executing for a given iteration. Please do what I suggested and try again - you'll almost certainly find (discounting the incredibly unlikely event of a compiler bug) that you're simply not fully understanding the program flow.